# Integrate mxgraph with angular 4

Tags: angular, mxgraph

I have been searching about ways to integrate mxgraph with angular 4, but could not find and resources. I also read about including all the mxgraph files in the asset folder but then do no know how to go on further with it. If anyone has a working example or atleast know how to go about please post it.

Comment: You can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922708/how-to-integrate-mxgraph-with-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mxGraph in my Angular 4 project.
It was quite easy for basic functionality but in details i am facing some issues.
But of-course you can use mxGraph in Angular 4 project.
Simple just add `mxGraph` library in `assets` folder and include mxClient file in `.angular-cli.json` file

Comment: can you please provide an example of how you've done it

Comment: I have placed my mxGraph library folder here `Angular4Project > src > assets > mxGraphLibrary` and referenced `mxClient` file in .`angular-cli.json` file under scripts array.
Note: `mxClient.js` file is placed in mxGraph Library folder