# Unable to integrate mxGraph with angular 13 getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mxBasePath' of undefined"

Tags: angular, mxgraph

I installed **mxgraph** and **@typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph typings** from npm. Save the typings to dev dependencies and then added the typings to typeRoots in tsconfig.json as mentioned on the page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph.
Then I used the code snippet mentioned below

```
import factory from 'mxgraph';

const mx = factory({
  mxBasePath: '',
});
console.log(mx.mxClient.VERSION);
```

But I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mxBasePath' of undefined" in the browser.

I also followed Benjamin's answer [mxGraph and it's Types integration with angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186662/mxgraph-and-its-types-integration-with-angular-8) here and can use the methods by using declare but the mxBasePath error still persists.

So if anyone has a solution please share. Thanks a lot.